# Eclipse completion proposals about external javascript libraries

Tags: eclipse, javascript

I'm trying to develop a javascript project with eclipse. I created a JavaScript Project and I added many external JS libraries (Right click on Project --> JavaScript --> Include Path --> Add JavaScript Library ...). After this, I expected completion proposals (what is obtained with **CTRL** + **space**, just to be clear) during the development of the script in my HTML page about my external libraries, but I have no suggestions. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to have powerful JavaScript completion inside Eclipse, I suggest you that you install [tern.java](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Getting-Started) (disclaimer, I'm the author of tern.java). It support several JavaScript  frameworks like jQuery, node, RequireJS, Angular.